# npm : cannot load file-dependencies of a tgz's dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have trouble to use a custom npm build I lib and put inside a tgz in another project, because of it files-dependencies

I want to bundle a custom lib npm and its files-dependencies inside a tgz.

the tgz:

```
->myLib.tgz/
--->myLib.js
--->package.json
--->node_modules/
--->libs/
------->lib1/
--------->lib1.js
--------->package.json
...
```

the package.json of myLib:(stored inside the tgz)

```
{
  name:myLib ,...
  dependencies:{
     lib1:"./libs/lib1/"
   }
 }
```

The issue, when I put myLib.tgz in a package.json of another project and do an npm install, I have this error:

```
Could not install "directoryWhereMyLibIs/myLib.tgz/libs/lib1" as it is not a directory and is not a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or .tar
```

the package.json

```
{name:otherProject
dependencies:{myLib:"directoryWhereMyLibIs/myLib.tgz"}

}
```

what can I do?